# how to internatianalize the ruby on rails site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, content-management-system, internationalization

We have the rails app, content served from the database. Now we need to translate that to multiple languages. What is the best way to the internalization of the ruby on rails application?

Comment: It's spelt "internationalization" or "internationalisation" or "i18n".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the plugin Globalize2 http://github.com/joshmh/globalize2

Answer (score 0):

Try using [localized record](http://github.com/glennpow/localized_record) to add translations for your content.